# Contact Roles Association in Opportunity Related List on Contact Layout

Tags: lightning-experience, related-list, opportunitycontactrole

I want to see the contact roles associations inside the Opportunity related list placed on Contact page Layout. But my current opportunity list is visible as below.

[image]

Is there any method that I can acheive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OCR (Opportunity Contact Role) is specific to an Opportunity. If you don't already have the related list enabled on Opportunity for OCR, that's the first thing I recommend you do. Also, in Lightning Experience, OCR works a bit different than it does in Classic. See [Salesforce Help](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=contactroles_add.htm&type=5).

I'd expect you will need to create a related list on your contact page layout for Opportunity using a related list component. If the contact doesn't have any related Opportunities you can set the visibility of the component to false so it won't appear and will be hidden.

Be aware of the following when it comes to creating Opportunities from Contacts as found in Salesforce Help:

> When you create an opportunity from a contact detail page, that contact becomes the primary contact on the opportunity. However, a contact role isn’t automatically assigned.

With all that said, without a custom component, I do not believe you'll be able to see the actual role unless you have it on the related opportunity for the contact as a field you display in the related list. When I tested this OCR was not an object that showed as available for me as a related record to Contact. I believe this is because a Contact can have many opportunity contact roles, each one dependent on the Opportunity you relate the Contact to.

Comment: I have already enabled the related list on Opportunity for OCR. Can you explain me how can I create a related list on for Opportunity on Contact. I already have a related list for Opportunity on Contact as in the given screenshot. But it doesn't show any contact role associations

Comment: @RuklaniAttanyake If a contact is related to an Opportunity, you'll see the Opportunity but without a custom component, when I attempted to do what you're asking in my own DE Org, I couldn't see a way to do this without creating a custom component. OCR isn't a standard related record one can access from the related list component. If you can create an action that has an OCR field on it, then you'd be able to see the field. I couldn't do that when I attempted this. The visible fields on related Opps are controlled by the action you associate with it.